# Sending an AJAX request to rails controller, then a HTTParty to external service, which returns JSON to output in .html.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am attempting to send an AJAX response to my rails controller, which will then send a HTTParty request to an external service. I am doing it this was because their would be a CORS issue if I sent a AJAX request straight from the JS. After the HTTParty, I need to receive the JSON it returns and output that on the .html.erb file.  It seems complicated, but I just need a little bit of assistance implementing its functionality;

We begin by sending the AJAX request to our rails backend by doing the following.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/gametitle",
        type: "post",
        data : {title: gametitle}
    });
```

The data send would look something like {"title": "AC3"}

This AJAX request would go to the routes file which looks like this:

```
   match '/gametitle' => 'loadtests#gametitle_post', via: :post
```

This route would then send it to the loadtest controllers gametitle_post method. Which looks like the following:

```
 def gametitle_post
    @gametitle = params[:title]
    HTTParty.post("http://supersecret.com/loadtests",
    :query => { :title => @gametitle })


    render nothing: true
 end
```

This is meant to receive the AJAX request, store the param sent, and then send a HTTParty request to receive JSON.  But this is where I am stuck at the moment. Whenever I try to output the variable in `@gametitle` by `console.log('<%= @gametitle %>` it is an empty string.

Thank you for any help that you can give me in assisting me with this problem.

Comment: Output your gametitle variable in controller to see the response gets back to the controller with right values. Furthermore, why are you using render nothing goes to true ? Since if you dont use it, it will still render the same page or will be on the same page.

Comment: @HassanAbbas I am doing the render nothing: true because if I do not do that then I am getting this error `POST http://localhost:3000/gametitle 500 (Internal Server Error)`                                                                                             In the server logs it is saying that it is missing a template, but I just want it to append to the current template

Comment: why dont you use just a return statement rather than this ?

Comment: @HassanAbbas What would I return? Just the response variable or true or false?

Comment: Just use return, that will serve your purpose.

Comment: I have edited my post do check it.

Comment: I'm still getting the same Internal Service Error

Comment: if you do you render nothing true, does rest things work out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
def gametitle_post
    @gametitle = params[:title]
    @some_variable = HTTParty.post("http://supersecret.com/loadtests",
    :query => { :title => @gametitle })

  //Access @some_variable in your view
    return
 end
```

Comment: Also check @some_variable has got the value what you need after receiving the data from HTTPParty post request.